# How can I unpack .7z files via MacOS terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, zip, compression

Looking to unpack a bunch of files.7z via terminal.

Is there a command-line tool built in, available or I shall install an application that comes with a graphical interface?

Comment: I found a solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/548349/how-can-i-install-7zip-so-i-can-run-it-from-terminal-on-os-x although I haven't tested it yet

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can install `p7zip` with Homebrew. So

```
% brew install p7zip
% 7za x myfiles.7z
```

Installing Homebrew as @EraserPencil suggested makes sense as the OP might need more programs in the future, which would be at his fingertips then. You can install Homebrew with

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It should be noted there is `7z e` as well but as commented by @Qback, this does almost never do what you want if you have subdirectories in the archive.

Comment: I have 7zip installed as well. Unfortunately, it said that the archive is damaged and failed to extract the file. Tried installing 7za and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 17):

The command line version of [Unarchive](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline) can extract .7z files.

Answer (score 11):

MacOS does not handle the .7z format natively.

[The UnArchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/) is my favourite tool for handling .7z and many other formats. It is available as both an application and a command line tool if that is how you prefer to operate.

Comment: Apples "Archive Utility" handles 7z these days - the question whether built-in command-line-tools can also handle it remains...

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to install homebrew, you can install [keka](https://www.keka.io) (which is an excellent gui for (un)compressing btw) and then link to the included version of p7zip found at `Keka.app/Contents/Resources/keka7z`

In order to make it function from the command line, I symlinked it into my `/usr/local/bin`

```
> ln -s /Applications/Keka.app/Contents/Resources/keka7z /usr/local/bin/7z
> 7z -h

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs x64)
Modified by aONe for Keka

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]
```

Comment: Nice solution. The symlink did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

We also found another totally free GUI solution that can run on macOS from [this other similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/548349/how-can-i-install-7zip-so-i-can-run-it-from-terminal-on-os-x)

[**Keka**](http://www.kekaosx.com) - the FREE macOS file un/archiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can install P7ZIP (version 16.02, tested on macOS [10.11](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rudix-mac/packages/master/p7zip-16.02-macos10.11.pkg) or [10.15](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rudix-mac/packages/master/p7zip-16.02-macos10.15.pkg)) from [Rudix](http://rudix.org). You don't have to install the Rudix ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, as of the time of writing, the official 7z distribution has a mac cli client [download](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) - currently [7-Zip 21.07 (2021-12-26)](https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2107-mac.tar.xz).

Download, unzip then run - works beatifully:

```
$ /Users/me/Downloads/7z2107-mac/7zz x some.7z
```

The first time you run it will fail with the "Unknown developer" prompt - you must give it permissions in the System preferences dialog

Answer (score 0):

The official 7z distribution release is available in brew.

`$ brew install sevenzip`

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sevenzip

Usage (cli):

```
$ 7zz -?

7-Zip (z) 23.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2023 Igor Pavlov : 2023-06-20
 64-bit locale=en_US.utf-8 Threads:12 OPEN_MAX:65535

Usage: 7zz <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...] [@listfile]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark
  d : Delete files from archive
  e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  h : Calculate hash values for files
  i : Show information about supported formats
  l : List contents of archive
  rn : Rename files in archive
  t : Test integrity of archive
  u : Update files to archive
  x : eXtract files with full paths
```

Answer (score -1):

While you got an error like this

```
MacBook-Air ~ % brew install p7zip
Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.
```

**Use bellow code for M1 Chip Mac**

```
arch -arm64 brew install p7zip
```

Comment: What do you need `arch -arm64` for here?

Comment: highly required ```arch -arm64``` in M1 Chip MacBook, if you try to install without ```arch -arm64``` then got an error.

Comment: Then your setup is strange. Works without that for me (and others). May be worth asking a new question for this so people can help you to avoid this.

Comment: Setup is not strange, M1 Chip architecture is ```arch -arm64``` that's why we need to install any brew command with the same architecture, other intel base mac no need to add ```arch -arm64```.

Comment: arch is only required if you want to pick a specific architecture from an universal binary. By default an M1 machine will automatically pick arm64 without any help from the user (unless you set your Terminal to run with Rosetta, but this isn‘t the standard case).

Comment: Anyway, what kind of error do you get when you run brew without arch?

Comment: You only get this error if you run a shell in x86/rosetta (see the beginning of https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10313 for more details). Just make sure the shell runs natively.

Answer (score -4):

Because you are familiar with CLI and coming from a Linux background, you could try [Installing GNU-tar on Mac](https://medium.com/@moschan/installing-gnu-tar-on-mac-827a494b1c1)

You'd first need to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh),

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then run `brew install gnu-tar`. Think of `brew` as the `yum`, or `apt-get` equivalent.

Then you can use `gtar` on your Mac.

```
# on Mac
$ gtar czvf example.tar.gz example
example/
example/bla.txt

# send it to CentOS
# login to CentOS

$ tar xzvf example.tar.gz
example/
example/bla.txt
```

Comment: AFAIK `tar` does not extract/unpack `.7z` files.